# How can we find the process ID of a running Windows Service?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I'm looking for a good way to find the process ID of a particular Windows Service.

In particular, I need to find the pid of the default "WebClient" service that ships with Windows. It's hosted as a "local service" within a svchost.exe process. I see that when I use netstat to see what processes are using what ports it lists [WebClient] under the process name, so I'm hoping that there is some (relatively) simple mechanism to find this information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`QueryServiceStatusEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684941%28VS.85%29.aspx) returns a [`SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685992%28VS.85%29.aspx), which contains the process identifier for the process under which the service is running.

You can use [`OpenService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330%28VS.85%29.aspx) to obtain a handle to a service from its name.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I think it should be OpenService rather than CreateService to obtain the handle, though.

Comment: No problem; you're correct about `OpenService`; I've fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimalist C++ function to do exactly what you want:

```
DWORD GetServicePid(const char* serviceName)
{
    const auto hScm = OpenSCManager(nullptr, nullptr, NULL);
    const auto hSc = OpenService(hScm, serviceName, SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);

    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssp = {};
    DWORD bytesNeeded = 0;
    QueryServiceStatusEx(hSc, SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&ssp), sizeof(ssp), &bytesNeeded);

    CloseServiceHandle(hSc);
    CloseServiceHandle(hScm);

    return ssp.dwProcessId;
}
```