# .NET: How to get a Process object, given the service name?

Tags: .net, service, process, system.diagnostics

Given a service name (such as `SNMPTRAP`) how can I get a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object?

So far I have found the [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fs05y7h%28v=vs.100%29) class and the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class but can't seem to get one from the other.

Comment: Looks like an interop call to `QueryServiceStatusEx` might be required.  See related question in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774129/how-can-we-find-the-process-id-of-a-running-windows-service.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like WMI works without having to resort to interop/Win32. Below is a proof-of-concept:

```
    private static Process ProcessFromServiceName(string serviceName)
    {
        // Note abuse of foreach as a lazy way of getting first item.
        // Also assumes that the first service in the collection is the correct one.

        string queryText = String.Format(   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                            "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='{0}'",
                                            serviceName);
        var query = new SelectQuery(queryText);
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
        {
            int processId = (int)(uint)service.Properties["ProcessId"].Value;
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            return process;
        }
        return null;
    }
```