# VB.NET; Can this WMI query be optmized more?

Tags: vb.net, service, process, wmi, pid

So my application iterates through the systems services, and gets some various information about them. One of them is the PID, which I use the following code to obtain (add one button, and reference to System.Management):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myStopWatch As New Stopwatch
    myStopWatch.Start()

    Dim processId As UInteger = 0
    Dim strService As String = "BITS"
    Dim qry As String = "SELECT PROCESSID FROM WIN32_SERVICE WHERE NAME = '" & strService & "'"
    Dim searcher As System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher = New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(qry)

    For Each mngntObj As System.Management.ManagementObject In searcher.[Get]()
        processId = CUInt(mngntObj("PROCESSID"))
    Next

    myStopWatch.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show("ID: " & processId.ToString & vbNewLine & myStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString)
End Sub
```

Now I have this as it's own function in my main application, not on a button (just for testing purposes).

This all works, and I can go thru services all fine I'm just curious if this can be optimized anymore? This takes about 17-20ms to obtain the PID, but can add up to a couple seconds depending on how many services are running.

So I'm curious, is there anyway to optimize this query?
Thanks.

For anyone wondering, I received this bit of code [from this msdn post.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a979351c-800f-41e7-b153-2d53ff6aac29/how-to-get-running-windows-service-process-id-?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Not unless you can convince MS to improve the performance of WMI. Your code doesn't contain anything that can be optimized, because it's performance is entirely dependent on the speed that WMI works.

Comment: @Ken White: Thanks, that's all I needed to know. New to WMI so wasn't sure if there was anything else that could be done.

Comment: You could try using the service api functions as described in the answer to: [How can we find the process ID of a running Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774129/how-can-we-find-the-process-id-of-a-running-windows-service).

Comment: @TnTinMn: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: 1.In normal scenarios you should ensure to exit the loop to avoid iterating more than one item (eg. multiple instance programs). 2.There are some properties of the System.Management.EnumerationOptions class that you can set to try optimize the execution time of the WMI query: ReturnImmediately = True; Rewindable = False; DirectRead = True and EnumerateDeep = False; you can pass it to the ManagementObjectSearcher constructor.

Comment: This timings you're reporting are very high. A query for all Services status shouldn't take more than 200~300 milliseconds to complete on a local machine. As @ElektroStudios said, you probably want to skip the deep enumeration, and query a service superclass dependancies in a subsequent query (as the Management Console does). If the query is performed on a remote machine, that's a different story.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Thanks! I wasn't aware these options existed, still learning my way around this.

Comment: @Jimi Wow, wasn't aware it should be that fast. Aye, I'll be looking into changing that. Thanks!

Comment: See: [System.Management.EnumerationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.enumerationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), [System.Management.Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.Management.ConnectionOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). If you have problems, comment back.